# Multiple lists with drag & drop within group

Tags: html, angular

I have two *div*s in a parent component. And there are cards (components rendered in *div*s) in each of the above two divs. Each card has got a list of employees (also *div*s) from which I want to drag any across other cards within their own parent div.

Below image shows how my page look like:

[image]

I want the page to be able to drag employees within Pickup or Drop. For eg: move Employee1 from {Place1 To Place2} to {Place3 To Place2} I have used cdkDropList/cdkDrag, however I could not drag anything at all.

Below is my html for parent component with the Pickup & Drop divs:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h5 class="bg-primary text-white">Pickup</h5>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Pickup DIV -->
<div class="row" cdkDropListGroup>
    <div class="col col-md-4" *ngFor="let item of pickupCabs" cdkDropList [cdkDropListData]="item.AssignedEmployees"
        (cdkDropListDropped)="onDrop($event)">
        <app-admin-special-request-allocation-card [allocatedCab]="item"
            (childevent)="onSpecialRequestReallocation($event)" cdkDrag>
        </app-admin-special-request-allocation-card>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h5 class="bg-primary text-white">Drop</h5>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Drop DIV -->
<div class="row" cdkDropListGroup>
    <div class="col col-md-4" *ngFor="let item of dropCabs" cdkDropList [cdkDropListData]="item.AssignedEmployees"
        (cdkDropListDropped)="onDrop($event)">
        <app-admin-special-request-allocation-card [allocatedCab]="item"
            (childevent)="onSpecialRequestReallocation($event)" cdkDrag>
        </app-admin-special-request-allocation-card>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is my html for the individual cards/routes (app-admin-special-request-allocation-card.component.html)

```
<div class="card bg-light shadow p-3 mb-4 bg-white corners mt-2 mb-2">
    <div class="card-body text-center">
        <div [class.alert-danger]="!isAllocatedSuccess" [class.alert-success]="isAllocatedSuccess" class="alert"
            *ngIf="isAllocated">{{message}}</div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col text-right">
                <span><b>{{allocatedCab.AllocationStatusText}}</b></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <i class='fas fa-{{allocatedCab.CabType|lowercase}}' style='font-size:30px;'></i>
                <br>
                <b>{{allocatedCab.Occupance}}/{{allocatedCab.Capacity}}</b>
                <p><b><span>{{allocatedCab.RouteType}}</span></b></p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <p><b><span>{{allocatedCab.PickupPoint}} To {{allocatedCab.DropPoint}}</span></b></p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <p style="text-align: left"><b><span>{{allocatedCab.VendorName}} -
                            {{allocatedCab.CabName}} - {{allocatedCab.RegNo}}</span></b></p>
            </div>

            <!-- employee list -->
            <div class="row" *ngFor="let employee of allocatedCab.AssignedEmployees">
                <p style="text-align: left"><span class="fa fa-user"></span>
                    <a href="./admin#" (click)="open(content,allocatedCab,employee)">
                        {{employee.FirstName}} {{employee.LastName}} -
                        <small> {{employee.PickupDate | date: "hh:mm a"}} </small>
                    </a>
                    <i style="color:red; cursor: pointer;" class="fa fa-remove"
                        (click)="openConfirmation(content1, employee)"></i></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 pt-2 text-left ">
                <span>{{allocatedCab.PickupDate | date: "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a"}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is a mistake in your code. The *cdkDropList* attribute is placed in the wrong div. And the *cdkDrag* attribute should be given to the exact div which can be draggable. So only give *cdkDropListGroup* attribute in parent div and place *cdkDropList* attribute inside the card component. ie.

1. You don't need *cdkDropList* attribute and the following code in that element in your parent div (Pickup and Drop).
2. Instead, add it in app-admin-special-request-allocation-card.component.html to a new wrapping div over the employee list div.
3. Add the *cdkDrag* attribute to exact div in which employee name is rendered.

try the below code.

**Parent Component**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
  <h5 class="bg-primary text-white">Pickup</h5>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row" cdkDropListGroup>
<!-- remove the 'cdkDropList' attribute and [cdkDropListData]=" from below div -->
  <div class="col col-md-4" *ngFor="let item of pickupCabs">
    <app-admin-special-request-allocation-card [allocatedCab]="item" (childevent)="onSpecialRequestReallocation($event)">
    </app-admin-special-request-allocation-card>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
  <h5 class="bg-primary text-white">Drop</h5>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row" cdkDropListGroup>
<!-- remove the 'cdkDropList' attribute and [cdkDropListData]=" from below div -->
  <div class="col col-md-4" *ngFor="let item of dropCabs">
    <app-admin-special-request-allocation-card [allocatedCab]="item" (childevent)="onSpecialRequestReallocation($event)">
    </app-admin-special-request-allocation-card>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Card Component**

```
<div class="card bg-light shadow p-3 mb-4 bg-white corners mt-2 mb-2">
    <div class="card-body text-center">
        <div [class.alert-danger]="!isAllocatedSuccess" [class.alert-success]="isAllocatedSuccess" class="alert" *ngIf="isAllocated" >{{message}}</div>
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col text-right" >
                    <span><b>{{allocatedCab.AllocationStatusText}}</b></span>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                    <i class='fas fa-{{allocatedCab.CabType|lowercase}}' style='font-size:30px;'></i>
                    <br>
                    <b>{{allocatedCab.Occupance}}/{{allocatedCab.Capacity}}</b>
                    <p><b><span>{{allocatedCab.RouteType}}</span></b></p>
            </div>
            <!-- Add the cdkDropList attribute and drop list data here -->>
            <div class="col-md-9 border-bottom" cdkDropList [cdkDropListData]="allocatedCab.AssignedEmployees" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
                    <div class="row">
                      <p><b><span>{{allocatedCab.PickupPoint}} To {{allocatedCab.DropPoint}}</span></b></p>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="row">
                        <p style="text-align: left"><b><span>{{allocatedCab.VendorName}} - {{allocatedCab.CabName}} - {{allocatedCab.RegNo}}</span></b></p>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Add cdkDrag attribute here -->>
                    <div class="row" *ngFor="let employee of allocatedCab.AssignedEmployees" cdkDrag>
                        <p style="text-align: left"><span class="fa fa-user"></span>
                        <a href="./admin#" (click)="open(content,allocatedCab,employee)">
                            {{employee.FirstName}} {{employee.LastName}} - 
                            <small> {{employee.PickupDate | date: "hh:mm a"}} </small>
                        </a>
                        <i style="color:red; cursor: pointer;" class="fa fa-remove" (click)="openConfirmation(content1, employee)"></i></p>
                    </div>
            </div>
     </div>  
     <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 pt-2 text-left ">
                    <span>{{allocatedCab.PickupDate | date: "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a"}}</span> 
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It is not mandatory to give *cdkDropListGroup* and *cdkDropList* in the same component. When the above code is rendered in the browser, the structure of the  *cdkDropListGroup* and *cdkDropList* will be set as parent and child relation. So I hope, you may get what you require.